# How to set max-old-space-size for typescript compiler (tsc)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have `tsc` job failing on gitlab ci with
`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

The script I'm running is
`tsc -p test/tsconfig.json --noEmit`

What I've tried so far is to increase `max-old-space-size` via:

1. `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 yarn print:heapsize && tsc -p test/tsconfig.json --noEmit`
2. `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' yarn print:heapsize && tsc -p test/tsconfig.json --noEmit` (just extra quotes around var)
3. `node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p test/tsconfig.json --noEmit`

Options #1 and #2 doesn't work, and #3 works fine, but it doesn't sound okay to me to run the binary and pass param  to the `node cli`

**So my question is - how do I set `max-old-spce-size` for `tsc` via `env variables` or maybe there is another good way to do it?**

`yarn print:heapsize` is the script I used to check current size - it shows 8gb for both #1 and #2 here it is:

`"print:heapsize": "node -e \"console.log(' Current heap size:', (require('v8').getHeapStatistics().total_available_size  / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2), 'Gb')\""`

and here's the output [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first two options fail because the environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192` applies only to the first command (`yarn print:heapsize`) that is before `&&`.

If you remove `yarn print:heapsize &&` the environment will apply to the compilation command as expected:

`cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 tsc -p test/tsconfig.json --noEmit`

Comment: actually I started with this and raised to 8192, then 10240, and then 16384 - only after it kept failing I've added`print:heapsize`

Comment: but maybe I've chained it with something else that time will double check, thanks!

Comment: you're completelly right there was command chaining in my initial attempts, tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is run tsc with more ram, you can run it via npx and the new node-options arg:

```
npx --node-options="--max-old-space-size=16000" tsc
```

We have a really large code base and tsc runs out of memory fast.  We only use it for pre checkin type checking.  Just to see if anything failed to compile anywhere on top of tests.

This option seems to work really well and you can bump to as much memory as you desire if you have enough RAM installed.

Keep in mind, on really large code bases, this could literally take 10+ minutes to run, or longer.

Answer (score -4):

`tsc` is deprecated but you can use `ts-node` with `--max-old-space-size` in `NODE_OPTIONS`

Add this options in your `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' ts-node index.ts"
   }
}
```

Comment: in my case the reason was the chaining and `cross-env` usage instead of `cross-env-shell` which will pass war to everything that was chained

Comment: This is slightly misleading, the dedicated TSC NPM package is deprecated, correct, but the tsc command is not.  Typescript's npm pacakge now includes tsc in it's bin folder, tsc (the command) is still used to compile typescript, especially in production cloud pipelines... Ts-node is for local development only basically.